# EF Code First - linking entity to same dependent entity - delete cascade error

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

I have these two entities:

```
public class Profile
{
    public int ProfileID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
}

public class Friend : BaseEntity
{
    public int FriendID { get; set; }

    public int ProfileID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProfileID")]
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }

    public int FriendProfileID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FriendProfileID")]
    public Profile FriendProfile { get; set; }
}
```

I think it is clear what I'm looking to do.  I want a Profile to be able to have a collection of Friends that reference other profiles.  Without specifying anything in the OnModelCreating, I get the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.Friends_dbo.Profiles_FriendProfileID' on table 'Friends' may
>   cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

So that means I need to specify a WillCascadeOnDelete(false) using the fluent API in the OnModelCreating method on the context.  However, I can't seem to figure out the right syntax using these relationships.

How do I resolve the cascade delete cycle and get entity framework to tolerate this relationship?

Comment: Are you trying to make Profile.Friends the other end of the navigation properties Friend.Profile and Friend.FriendProfile?  Or is it just for one of them, or none of them?

Comment: Trying to make it the other end of Friend.Profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that you need to add a fluent mapping to OnModelCreating().  Try something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Friend>()
                .HasOptional(x => x.FriendProfile )  //or HasRequired
                .WithMany()
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Looks like that worked, except I had to do two of those statements.  One for Profile and one for FriendProfile.